# how to call async task with different url

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I need to call asynctask with different urls. i have three button, they do a http post to server with different urls, now i can call asynctask with one url but how can i call the same function with different urls.the following is my asynctask class:

```
private class Downloadfiles extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, JSONObject>{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jo) {
        try {
            cards = jo.getInt("cards");
            points = jo.getInt("points");
            cash = jo.getInt("cash");
        } catch (JSONException e1) {            
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //cardsv.startAnimation(textio);
        cardsv.setText(""+cards);
        cashv.setText(""+cash);

        Log.e("wintype", "msg" + wintype);  
        super.onPostExecute(jo);
    }



    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params) {
        Log.e("msg++--", "play game method called");

        BufferedReader reader=null;
        data_to_send = "userId=" + userId ;

        try
        { 
           Log.e("inside try block playgame", "get text" + data_to_send);
          // Defined URL  where to send data
      URL url = new URL(playgame);
   // Send POST data request
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
    conn.setDoOutput(true);                   
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
    wr.write(data_to_send);
    wr.flush();     

    // Get the server response 
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line = null;

  // Read Server Response
  while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      {
             // Append server response in string
             sb.append(line + "\n");
             Log.e("inside playgame", "while loop");
      }


  play_response = sb.toString();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      Log.e("MyTag ", "Failure to get json data in playgame--1--", ex);
  }
  finally
  {
      try
      {

          reader.close();
      }

      catch(Exception ex) {
          Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get json data in playgame--2--", ex);
      }
  }
  Log.e("play response from the server in ", "play game" + play_response);

  JSONObject jo = null;
try {
    jo = new JSONObject(play_response);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


    return jo;
}
```

}

and i am calling this with one of my buttons click

```
Downloadfiles download = new Downloadfiles();
 downloads.execute();
```

Comment: downloads.execute(url1) like this u can pass arguments in execute

Comment: ya i tried but   URL url = new URL(playgame); URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); gives me error

Comment: what is playgame here ? where did u declared it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
private class Downloadfiles extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, JSONObject>{
```

to

```
private class Downloadfiles extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>{
```

And change

```
@Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params) {
        Log.e("msg++--", "play game method called");
```

to

```
@Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
       String url= urls[0];// get the URL String here
```

**And Finally call the** `AsyncTask` like

```
new Downloadfiles (this).execute(URL1);// For Button1
```

and

```
new Downloadfiles (this).execute(URL2);//For Button2 and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the url as a parameter in the constructor of async task.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask < Params , Progress, Result >

In your case you declared an AsyncTask< URL, Integer , JSONObject > it mean you ll provide

- Params of type : URL
- Progress : Integer
- Result : JSONObject

the Method doInBackground(URL... params) accept multiplme parameters,
(URL... params) is equivalent to (URL[] params), and you can use it like :

```
URL[] urls= ....."many url here" ; 
Downloadfiles download = new Downloadfiles(urls);
downloads.execute();
```

inside doInBackground Loop over urls to do job

Answer (score 0):

Pass the url as a parameter in the constructor of async task.

change

```
 private class Downloadfiles extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, JSONObject>
```

to

```
private class Downloadfiles extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>
```

And change

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... params)
```

to

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params)



 private class Downloadfiles extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>{
       String URL;
      Context _context;

        public Downloadfiles (Context context, String URL)
    {
         this.URL = URL;
         _context = context;
    }
 }
```

**Call it from activity like this**

Button 1

```
new  Downloadfiles (MainActivity.this, "URL1").execute();
```

Button 2

```
new  Downloadfiles (MainActivity.this, "URL2").execute();
```